# simple mail() which will generate a fetched report from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

sending mail in php using simple `mail()` function.

i want to send mail which will generate a report that is fetched from mysql database but the `mail()` expects 4 parameteres`mail($to,$subject,$message,$from)` i am not able to generate the `$message` as it will hold the body of the mail with fetched values and specific format.

my `script.php` to generate report:-

```
<?php
$to  = 'abc@gmail.com' . ', ';
$subject = 'Test Mail';

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from table_name ");

echo'<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<h1>Test User</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1">

<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>user</th>
<th>phoneCount</th>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";      
echo "</html>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

as i got the value of $to, $subject, $headers but the $msg is creating the problem.how can i get to send the mail with this format.i cannot figure out how to get the body of mail in $msg which will generate reports

Comment: You're echoing your content to the screen instead of capturing it in you `$msg` variable.

Comment: where do i need that variable to store.is it in the echo <html> part that i need to assign the variable or the query for the mysql statement.and if i assign the variable i wont be able to see it in browsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in it's simplest form instead of echo'ing the content out you want to get it assigned to a variable.

You've got a couple of options to do this:

1) Variable concatination

```
$message = '<p>Line 1</p>';
$message .= '<p>' . $line2 . '</p>';
$message .= '<p>Line 3</p>';
```

The contents of $message would then be:

```
<p>Line 1</p><p>Line 2</p><p>Line 3</p>
```

2) Output buffering

```
ob_start(); // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

echo '<p>Line 1</p>';
echo '<p>' . $line2 . '</p>';
echo '<p>Line 3</p>';

$message = ob_get_clean(); // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php
```

3) Heredoc Syntax (This approach can get tricky I wouldn't recommend it right now)

```
$message = <<<EOT

<p>Line 1</p>
<p>$line2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>

EOT;
```

Each of these 3 approaches will let you get the content assigned into $message.

However by default mail will only send a plain text email.  If you want to send a HTML email you need to set specific headers and ideally you should set multipart boundaries etc.  I'd probably recommend using a library like Zend's which you can include piecemeal.  Failing that here's a basic example: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
echo'<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<h1>Test User</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1">

<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>user</th>
<th>phoneCount</th>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";      
echo "</html>";
```

to be something like below:

```
$msg = '<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<h1>Test User</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1">';

$msg = $msg . "<tr>";
$msg = $msg . "<th>id</th>";
$msg = $msg . "<th>user</th>";
$msg = $msg . "<th>phoneCount</th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
$msg = $msg . "<tr>";
$msg = $msg ."<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
$msg = $msg ."<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
$msg = $msg ."<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
$msg = $msg ."</tr>";
}
$msg = $msg . "</table>";      
$msg = $msg . "</html>";
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$msg' (T_VARIABLE) missing semicolon or something in he format when i run it in browser

Comment: maybe the <table border="1" cellspacing="1">'; ending with '; will be in $msg = $msg . "<th>phoneCount</th>"'; doing this showing no error.

Comment: To clean this up you could opt for .= instead of = $msg . 'blah' and instead of breaking out of the string you could interpolate the array values like: "<td>{$row['id']}</td>"